# Tangerine `tangy-input` onkeyup event

Tags: html, forms, web-component

I am working on a Tangerine based form and I want to do something upon a `onkeyup` event. Is there a way to access it in `tangy-input`. Here is a non-working solution I tried. Or is it not totally supported?

```
<tangy-input name="name" label="Name" @onkeyup="${() => this.logChar()}"></tangy-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the right attribute for handling the `keyup` event for `tangy-input`. But I found a work around which is using 'paper-input'.

```
<paper-input name="name" label="Name" @keyup="${(event) => this.logChar(event)}"></paper-input>
```